# Baby-Step-Giant-Step transformation Question

Tags: discrete-logarithms

In most texts, the BSGS Algorithm solves $$g^x = b \bmod p$$ for x by rewriting the expression to $$g^{jm+i} = b \bmod p$$

then do:

$$g^i = b(g^{-m})^j \bmod p$$

This requires to compute the inverse of $g$. Whats wrong if I transform it this way?: $$g^{jm+i} = b \bmod p$$ to $$g^{jm} + g^{i} = b \bmod p$$ and then lastly: $$g^{i} = \frac{b}{g^{jm}} \bmod p$$

This division of $g^{jm}$ should be possible, when p is prime right? Why can't I compute the Giant Steps, with the expression I got on the right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's the same exact thing:  $bg^{-mj} = \frac{b}{g^{jm}}$ by laws of exponents.  We just hate writing "division" in modular arithmetic.

Comment: Also, you are missing that $i$ and $j$ run independently over the same index set.  You have to compute lots of terms with $i$ and *separately* lots of terms for $j$ and search for a match.  When you argue your way, you are assuming you already have the match in hand.

Comment: Let's assume $p = 29, g = 11$ and $b = 3$

, m is ceil(sqrt(p)) = 6 .

If I do it by the texts, I calculate inverse of g first -> 8 .

Then lets take j = 2 for example. I do $3*(8^{6})^2 \bmod 29$, which is 14 .

If I do it my proposed way for j = 2: $\frac{3}{11^{6*2}} \bmod 29$, which is some very small number and not 18.

Comment: That's my whole point.  You do not know ahead of time the particular values of $i$ and $j$ that will make a match.  Why should they be equal for $j=2$?

Comment: Im not talking about the indexes $i$ at all in the moment, just the expressions on the right side, that you said were the exact same thing. It appears they are not.

Comment: You are doing something wrong on your calculator:  they are equal.  I just checked.

Comment: I have a guess that you are accidentally calculating $\left( \frac{b}{g^j}\right)^m$, committing an order-of-operations error.

Comment: I also get the same numbers, when I don't take the modular inverse for $g$ in $g^{-m}$ and just calculate it the "normal" way. I have a guess that you are not calculating the inverse  $g^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand.  You either calculate $g^{-m}$ or you calculate $h^m$ where $h=g^{-1}$ (because they are the same thing).  Are you by chance accidentally computing $h^{-m}$, thereby killing the inverse by accident?